# Threejs - Applying a texture to plane always renders black,

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to apply a texture to a plane. I am using and image that is 256x256. Currently it just renders black. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
//create the floor

var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'carpet.jpg' ); //256x256
floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position.y = -0.5;
floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(floor);
```

I can add more of my code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be because you texture gets scaled down(so it can be repeated 100 times on the surface) and you just can't see the details of it? If the texture is dark itself this could be the matter. Maybe you try it with `floorTexture.repeat.set(1, 1);` to see if it actually gets applied.

Also you may consider to include your texture, so that anyone can test against it. I just ran your code in r.58 with a custom texture and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this myself for a while. Check the image's filesystem permissions. Mine were set to 640. When I changed them to 664, the image rendered as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be lack of ambient light in the scene, try adding a white ambient light to see if it solves your problem